# ASP.Net MVC JQuery is unable to see one property from a ViewModel but can retrieve value from another property when calling from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is the error I am getting:

```
jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: RIC is not defined ReferenceError: RIC is not defined
```

Here is my simple javascript function

```html
<script>
    function additionalData()
    {
        return {
            employeeId: @Model.EmpId, //Able to retrieve this property
            terminalId: @Model.ServiceCenter //If I include this property, it throws the exception above
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I include the `@Model.ServiceCenter`, I get the error above.

If I hard-code it to be a value such as 'RIC', it works with no issue.

If I add a breakpoint, I can see that the model does contain a value for both properties.

Any idea why I can't retrieve the @Model.ServiceCenter property even though I can see there is a value associated with it?

[image: Here I show you the model properties contain a value]

Comment: The error message suggests that "RIC" is being interpreted as a field name, not a value.  Maybe try putting quotes around @Model.ServiceCenter?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm ashamed to admit I never considered trying to surround it in quotes. I figured that was the error but never thought that would be the solution. It worked and I thank you so much! I have been banging my heading my head on this for too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use:

```
terminalId: '@Model.ServiceCenter'
```

This will work as the value RIC coming in this is string
and your `employeeId` is integer